# Upgrading to haml 6 causes ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `safe_concat' for {:add_to_stack=>true}:Hash) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, ruby-on-rails-7, ruby-3

We are using haml 5.2.2 + Ruby 3.2 + Rails 7 + haml-rails 2.1 in our app.

When I to upgrade to haml 6.1.1, my rails views start failing with the exception:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `safe_concat' for {:add_to_stack=>true}:Hash)
```

The stack trace points to the first line in whatever partial is rendered first.

I tried catching the ActionView::Template::Error and inspecting the backtrace and see something like this:

```
/Users/me/project_directory/app/views/admin/shared/_index_header.haml:8:in `_app_views_admin_shared__index_header_haml___3465718130954218663_135720'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/base.rb:244:in `public_send'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/base.rb:244:in `_run'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:361:in `instrument_render_template'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-1.0.2/lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:104:in `block in profile_method'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:251:in `block in render_partial_template'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:246:in `render_partial_template'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:237:in `render'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:81:in `render_partial_to_object'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:53:in `render_partial'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:44:in `render'",
/Users/me/project_directory/app/views/admin/users/index.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_admin_users_index_html_haml___942898265407221281_135700'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/base.rb:244:in `public_send'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/base.rb:244:in `_run'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:361:in `instrument_render_template'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-1.0.2/lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:104:in `block in profile_method'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:60:in `block in render_template'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:75:in `block in render_with_layout'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:74:in `render_with_layout'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `render_template'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:11:in `render'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:61:in `render_template_to_object'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:29:in `render_to_object'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:117:in `block in _render_template'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/base.rb:270:in `in_rendering_context'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:116:in `_render_template'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:216:in `_render_template'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:46:in `render_to_body'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141:in `render_to_body'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `render'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in render'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/benchmark.rb:311:in `realtime'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `ms'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22:in `block in render'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:91:in `cleanup_view_runtime'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:34:in `cleanup_view_runtime'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:21:in `render'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:35:in `default_render'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `block in send_action'",
<internal:me>:90:in `tap'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:215:in `process_action'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:53:in `process_action'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in process_action'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:66:in `use_zone'",
/Users/me/project_directory/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:28:in `default_timezone'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:233:in `process_action'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:67:in `block in process_action'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:66:in `process_action'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:259:in `process_action'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in `process'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionview-7.0.4.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-1.0.2/lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:104:in `block in profile_method'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:188:in `dispatch'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:251:in `dispatch'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:852:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sentry-rails-4.1.7/lib/sentry/rails/rescued_exception_interceptor.rb:12:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-attack-6.6.1/lib/rack/attack.rb:127:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:38:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:36:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:704:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:603:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99:in `run_callbacks'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:28:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:26:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/lograge-0.11.2/lib/lograge/rails_ext/rack/logger.rb:15:in `call_app'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `block in call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/request_store-1.5.0/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:137:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sentry-ruby-core-4.1.5/lib/sentry/rack/capture_exceptions.rb:29:in `block in call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sentry-ruby-core-4.1.5/lib/sentry/hub.rb:52:in `with_scope'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sentry-ruby-core-4.1.5/lib/sentry-ruby.rb:149:in `with_scope'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sentry-ruby-core-4.1.5/lib/sentry/rack/capture_exceptions.rb:14:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-cors-1.1.1/lib/rack/cors.rb:100:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-1.0.2/lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:281:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in `perform_request'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/configuration.rb:252:in `call'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/server.rb:441:in `process_client'",
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'"
```

As far as I can tell, NONE of those files contain a call to the `safe_concat` method. Where is this error coming from? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you add in a copy of your 
admin/shared/_index_header.haml and relevant extracts from your admin/shared controller?

Comment: I'm facing to same issue.
It's strange, `safe_concat` is rails's method.
My app run as well with ruby v2.x and rails 6.1.x.
However if I upgrade ruby to v3.x, this issue is appear.

Answer (score 1):

It's depended to your rails app and which gems are you using.

In my case, the issue from gem `xray-rails` which is installed on `development`.

I remove this gem then rails app works.

You should check the impaction from gems

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was xray-rails in my case as well